# What is optimal in spark: union then join or join then union?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given three different dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, which have the same schema, and `df3`. The three dataframes have one field in common.

Also consider that `df1` and `df2` have around 42 million records each and `df3` has around 100k records.

What is optimal in spark:

- Union `df1` and `df2`, then join with `df3`?
- Join `df1` with `df3`, join `df2` with `df3`, then union these two dataframes?

Comment: May be an idea to consider the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all honesty, with these volumes it does not really matter.

Looking at the .explain() on both approaches there is not much in it.

A `broadcast join` is evident in both cases. In addition `union` does not cause a 
`shuffle`, at least your question does not imply that, i.e. due to transformations that might cause that.

That is to say, performance is / should be equal. See below, simulated DF approach but demonstration of the points discussed. Mathematically not much in it to decide otherwise.

**Approach 1**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{sha1, rand, col}

val randomDF1 = (spark.range(1, 42000000)
   .withColumn("random_value", rand(seed=10).cast("string"))
   .withColumn("hash", sha1($"random_value"))
   .drop("random_value")
).toDF("id", "hash")

val randomDF2 = (spark.range(1, 42000000)
   .withColumn("random_value", rand(seed=10).cast("string"))
   .withColumn("hash", sha1($"random_value"))
   .drop("random_value")
).toDF("id", "hash")

val randomDF3 = (spark.range(1, 100000)
   .withColumn("random_value", rand(seed=10).cast("string"))
   .withColumn("hash", sha1($"random_value"))
   .drop("random_value")
).toDF("id", "hash")

val u = randomDF1.union(randomDF2) 
 val u2 = u.join(randomDF3, "id").explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(4) Project [id#25284L, hash#25296, hash#25326]
+- *(4) BroadcastHashJoin [id#25284L], [id#25314L], Inner, BuildRight
   :- Union
   :  :- *(1) Project [id#25284L, sha1(cast(random_value#25286 as binary)) AS hash#25296]
   :  :  +- *(1) Project [id#25284L, cast(rand(10) as string) AS random_value#25286]
   :  :     +- *(1) Range (1, 42000000, step=1, splits=2)
   :  +- *(2) Project [id#25299L, sha1(cast(random_value#25301 as binary)) AS hash#25311]
   :     +- *(2) Project [id#25299L, cast(rand(10) as string) AS random_value#25301]
   :        +- *(2) Range (1, 42000000, step=1, splits=2)
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false])), [id=#13264]
   +- *(3) Project [id#25314L, sha1(cast(random_value#25316 as binary)) AS hash#25326]
      +- *(3) Project [id#25314L, cast(rand(10) as string) AS random_value#25316]
         +- *(3) Range (1, 100000, step=1, splits=2)
```

**Approach 2**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{sha1, rand, col}

val randomDF1 = (spark.range(1, 42000000)
  .withColumn("random_value", rand(seed=10).cast("string"))
  .withColumn("hash", sha1($"random_value"))
  .drop("random_value")
).toDF("id", "hash")

val randomDF2 = (spark.range(1, 42000000)
   .withColumn("random_value", rand(seed=10).cast("string"))
   .withColumn("hash", sha1($"random_value"))
   .drop("random_value")
).toDF("id", "hash")

val randomDF3 = (spark.range(1, 100000)
   .withColumn("random_value", rand(seed=10).cast("string"))
   .withColumn("hash", sha1($"random_value"))
   .drop("random_value")
).toDF("id", "hash")

val u1 = randomDF1.join(randomDF3, "id") 
val u2 = randomDF2.join(randomDF3, "id") 
val u3 = u1.union(u2).explain() 

== Physical Plan ==
Union
:- *(2) Project [id#25335L, hash#25347, hash#25377]
:  +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#25335L], [id#25365L], Inner, BuildRight
:     :- *(2) Project [id#25335L, sha1(cast(random_value#25337 as binary)) AS hash#25347]
:     :  +- *(2) Project [id#25335L, cast(rand(10) as string) AS random_value#25337]
:     :     +- *(2) Range (1, 42000000, step=1, splits=2)
:     +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false])), [id=#13409]
:        +- *(1) Project [id#25365L, sha1(cast(random_value#25367 as binary)) AS hash#25377]
:           +- *(1) Project [id#25365L, cast(rand(10) as string) AS random_value#25367]
:              +- *(1) Range (1, 100000, step=1, splits=2)
+- *(4) Project [id#25350L, hash#25362, hash#25377]
   +- *(4) BroadcastHashJoin [id#25350L], [id#25365L], Inner, BuildRight
      :- *(4) Project [id#25350L, sha1(cast(random_value#25352 as binary)) AS hash#25362]
      :  +- *(4) Project [id#25350L, cast(rand(10) as string) AS random_value#25352]
      :     +- *(4) Range (1, 42000000, step=1, splits=2)
  +- ReusedExchange [id#25365L, hash#25377], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false])), [id=#13409]
```

Comment: You're welcome. Due to corona more time to look and answer!